# Легковесные GUI-приложения

Tags: windows, gui, c++

Задача заключается в создании оконного приложения (Windows), имеющего небольшой размер исполняемого файла и не содержащего зависимостей от внешних библиотек. Например, если писать с использованием Qt и поместить нужные библиотеки в exe-файл, размер этого файла будет несколько десятков мегабайт.

Какие есть альтернативы для создания оконных приложений с исполняемым файлом минимального размера (хотя бы <5 Мб)? Кроссплатформенность не нужна.

**UPDATE**

Альтернативные фреймворки предложены в комментариях к ответу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чистый [WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx). Можно с библиотекой [MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e.aspx).

exe-шник будет динамически линковаться с необходимыми бибилиотеками, которые поставляются с Windows.

Простенькая игра с компьютерным противником, рисованием по WM_PAINT и с меню у меня занимает 128кБ (в Release-сборке).

Comment: Что на чистом WinAPI, что на MFC писать код затруднительно, долго и нудно. Хотелось бы пойти более удобным путем.

Comment: @DarkGenius: Боюсь, более удобный путь заключается в использовании фреймворков. А для чего нужен небольшой размер? 2015 год всё же, интернет у всех быстрый.

Comment: @DarkGenius Вот Вам, пожалуйста, [FLTK][1]. В документации они хвастаются, что
> The "core" (the "hello" program compiled & linked with a static FLTK library using gcc on a 486 and then stripped) is 114K.

  [1]: http://www.fltk.org/

Comment: @DarkGenius, я Вам еще принес: [Ultimate++][1]. В [статье][2] пишут, что exe будет весить 2-3 Мб.

> Как отмечают разработчики, средний размер исполняемого файла полнофункционального приложения, при создании которого используется библиотека Ultimate++, будет 2-3 Мб. Сама среда разработки, созданная, естественно, при помощи этой же библиотеки, занимает 3,5 Мб (речь идёт об исполняемом файле - EXE).

  [1]: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate%2B%2B
  [2]: http://www.kv.by/index2007261105.htm

Comment: @VladD: Хотелось бы получать приложения, по размеру сравнимые с размером программ, написанных на Delphi. В Borland очень удачно придумали VCL: она обеспечивает и легкость разработки, и компактность приложения.

Comment: @atwice, спасибо!

Comment: >Простенькая игра с компьютерным противником, рисованием по WM_PAINT и с меню у меня занимает 128кБ (в Release-сборке).

Неправильный вы выбрали вектор сравнения. Преимущество WinAPI не в размере. С помощью WinAPI можно сделать все то, что нельзя делать с использованием фреймворков. Либо это придется делать в обход логики этих фреймворков. Поэтому выбор инструмента должен быть хорошо взвешен. Проект на сложных инструментах может просто не завершиться. Вы потратите деньги и время впустую еще на этапе проектирования, выбрав WinAPI просто потому что это круто.

Answer (score 1):

```
"затруднительно, долго и нудно"
```

Это только поначалу, потом наделаешь своих модулей, и будет всё писаться быстро.

```
"2015 год всё же, интернет у всех быстрый."
```

Дело не в интернете вовсе, правильная мысль у человека. Если нужная мне программа, найденная в сети, занимает больше 2-3мб, я её не использую, ибо это говорит о криворукости программиста или лени, когда этот функционал можно было запихнуть в 500кб.

```
The "core" (the "hello" program compiled & linked with a static FLTK library using gcc on a 486 and then stripped) is 114K.
```

1,14к она должна макс. занимать, а на ассемблере ещё раз в 10-20 меньше, ) т.ч. хвастаться нечем.

Comment: @Isaev: Ну, хотите маленькие программы, пишите на C# :)

Использование фреймворков говорит не о криворукости, а о прагматичности программиста, т. к. маленькие программы получаются обычно только если писать всё вручную.

Comment: > потом наделаешь своих модулей

В которых будут свои никому не известные баги.

> Если нужная мне программа, найденная в сети, занимает больше 2-3мб, я её не использую

Сочувствую.

> ибо это говорит о криворукости программиста или лени

Или о том, что программист ценит свое время.

Comment: @Nofate, можно подумать, что в чужих программах (в т.ч. в известных библиотеках и фреймворках) нет багов.

Comment: @avp, либа, написанная абстрактным самоуверенным Васей Пупкиным или какой-нибудь опенсорц фреймворк с нормальным процессом разработки, багтрекингом и прочим? Я голосую не в пользу Васи )

Просто потому, что известная либа обкатана на большом количестве пользователей, для нее есть known issues, наборы элегантных проверенных костылей и тикеты в джире. А своя либа протестирована только на себе, репрезентативность выборки - так себе.

Comment: @VladD, мои программы меня удовлетворяют, не я тему поднял)

Это привычка со всемён спектрума, когда была борьба за каждый байт и каждый такт в итоге всё летало на любой машине и занимало минимум места. Хорошие были времена и программисты были хорошие.

Comment: @Isaev: справедливости ради отмечу, что борьба за каждый байт имеет смысл только в маленьких проектах, в которых можно позволить себе роскошь отказаться от абстракции. В неигрушечных проектах на миллионы строк кода позволить себе оптимизировать каждую строку невозможно: не хватит человеческой жизни.

Comment: @VladD, бесспорно... Но когда например мелкомягкие пишут excel на пол гига, а другой разработчик укладывает 90% функционала в 1.5мб, это заслуживает уважения (Spread32 имею ввиду, http://www.byedesign.co.uk/)

Comment: @Isaev, в конце концов все зависит от задачи, которая поставлена. Если можно экономить силы и время не в ущерб результату и окружающей среде, то я не вижу причин идти более сложным путем. Надо взвешивать все за и против и не пускать свое время на бесполезные и ненужные дела.

--------

А excel так весит за счет графической составляющей и дизайнерских изысков только после 2000-х, в [отличие от первых версий на 1,5мб от 90-х годов](https://winworldpc.com/product/microsoft-excel/), которыми никто не запрещает пользоваться ;)